# Connecting copper wire to a nine volt battery

Tags: batteries

I don't have a cap for a nine volt battery so I am connecting to it with copper wire. Which connector is positive?

Have I wired these up correctly?
[image: Battery and wires]

Comment: Can I suggest taping over one of the terminals to stop a short circuit as your using multicore cable so one could touch the other terminal and then make the battery get very hot.

Comment: Already happened -- luckily I noticed and covered the middle and one terminal with a rubber band.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: @Toby - Mine because you shouldn't solder on batteries unless they have soldering tabs.

Comment: Yes, clearly he's doing it wrong - but, that's why he's asking for help

Comment: @Toby - Yes, but his question is not if what he's doing is alright (soldering), but if he soldered them on the right connections.

Comment: So tell me I should do it differently, instead of saying it's a bad question. The object of asking a question on SE is learning, and without asking a question, even if it's the wrong question, I can't do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the body of the battery - it will tell you.

The round one is positive, the crown shaped one is negative.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You have them reversed.
 The smaller round "male" one is positive.

[image]

=============================

**Making your own conector:**

Find a dead 9 volt battery.
 Tear its head off - aka, remove the terminals.
 This will push onto another battery and provide you with terminals.

Note that **on the connector** which you are making **the terminals are reversed**.
 On the connector the round pole is negative (unlike on the battery).

**This polarity for battery connector only:**

[image]

---

**Tools:**

You need a basic multimeter.
 In Cleveland you should be able to find one for $1 or so in a yard sale / garage sale ... or free. If you can't find one and can't afford one email me and tell me why I should ask somebody to give you one. Good enough story and I'll arrange for someone to do so. ((I'm in NZ :-) ).

You need a soldering iron.
 Ideally temperature controlled but anything no too large is a start. Smallish tip.

What are you powering with your battery?
 Who is Grandawn?

Answer (score 3):

You should **never** solder batteries unless they have soldering tabs.  9V battery snap connectors cost next to nothing,

[image]

and you'll avoid mistakes if you would get batteries like the one on the left:

[image]

The [full size image](http://earthsignals.com/add_CGC/Images/9V_Batts.jpg) seems to be inaccessible, but if you have a good look you'll see that the "+" marking on the left battery is on the wrong side. (I've been assured that it isn't photoshop'd.)